# Confusions about this statement in C?

Tags: c, c99

I found this code block in [The UNIX Programming Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013937681X) (published with a copyright date of 1984).

chp8->hoc3->symbol.c

```
char *emalloc(n)    /* check return from malloc */
unsigned n;
{
char *p, *malloc();

p = malloc(n);
if (p == 0)
    execerror("out of memory", (char *) 0);
return p;
}
```

What's the meaning of:

```
char *p, *malloc();
```

It's really strange?

Comment: It is old "Kernigan & Ritchie" C. The C standard has evolved a lot since.

Comment: [K&R C function declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%26R_C#K.26R_C)

Comment: Please change the book you read or get its updated edition if there's one, since it's very dated. It doesn't use function prototypes, the most important feature of C89 or ANSI C.

Comment: There isn't a new edition of the book, but it was published 5 years before there was a standard C.  It is actually a great book, but it is now showing its age and, in all honesty, can't easily be recommended for beginners, precisely because the C is so old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 char *p, *malloc();
```

is declaring a pointer to `char` named `p` and a function named `malloc` (In these K&R C days, `void*` did not exist).

This is old Kernigan & Ritchie [*C*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) (from the 1980s). The C standard has evolved significantly since that time. Current C standard is [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29), and its previous version [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) is very widely used.

Don't code this way today. `malloc` is defined in `<stdlib.h>` and it might be some [inlined function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) there (but usually is not).

Your function is often conventionally called `xmalloc` today; you'll need to add

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

in the start of your file (since `malloc` and `exit`is declared  in `<stdlib.h>`  and `EXIT_FAILURE` is defined there, and `perror` is declared in `<stdio.h>`), and would have been defined as

```
 void* xmalloc(size_t sz) {
    void* p = malloc(sz);
    if (!p) {
       perror("malloc");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
    return p;
 }
```

and declared in some header of yours with

```
 void* xmalloc(size_t sz);
```

I suggest reading a newer book. On Linux, consider at least the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book (which is dated from 2001).

If using GCC you could add [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to your function declaration.

Comment: but is it still valid in c99?

Comment: @tristan: The particular line in this answer is valid in C99, but not the code snippet posted in the original question.

Comment: @dreamlax: Is `char *malloc();` valid? Isn't the prototype of `malloc` different?

Comment: @legends2k: It is valid as long as the code has not previously declared a conflicting type (e.g. by including `stdlib.h`).

Comment: @dreamlax: Alright, so as a custom (non-standard) function it's valid, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the confusion comes from using an old book, which uses a very old version of C (called [*K&R C*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K&R_C)). I'll list them

**1. Standard functions declared unnecessarily**

`char *p, *malloc();`

can be broken into

```
char *p;
char *malloc();
```

The latter declares a function named `malloc` which returns a `char*`, there's no information on the type of arguments it takes. In modern C ([C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K&R_C#C11) or [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K&R_C#C99) or even C89), you'd do

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and start using `malloc` without worrying about its declaration, which would be `void* malloc(size_t size);` which comes from the included header.

**2. Function declaration and definitions used are archaic**

Say you've a function to add two integers, according to the old book you've, it'd declare it as `int add();` (or perhaps not declare it at all, since the default type is taken as `int` when undeclared) and define it as

```
 int add(x, y)
    int x;
    int y;
 {
    return x + y;
 }
```

While in modern C, you'd do declare it as `int add(int, int);` and define it as

```
 int add(int x, int y)
 {
     return x + y;
 }
```

These were standardized and called the [*ANSI C*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#ANSI_C_and_ISO_C), *ISO C* or *C89* (informally). [K&R's C book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) has 2 editions, the older edition suffers from the same issues your book has; hence it's recommended to use the 2nd edition which was written on ANSI C.

Comment: It's really a good answer. yours' and Basile Starynkevitch's both very great. so, I have to accept the oldest answer. many thx anyway.

Comment: Note that the second item is inaccurate; they are not function prototypes at all — and please don't abuse the accurate term 'prototype' to cover them.  They are old-style (or non-prototype) function definitions; and the declaration of `malloc()` is an old-style function declaration.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: They're function definitions (implementation) and I've written it so, no?

Comment: The heading says '2. Function prototypes used are archaic'. Also, you would probably not declare `add()` because it is a function returning an integer. If you did, you would write `int add();` — you can't mention the arguments by name or type in the declaration of the function (so `int add(x, y)` is a syntax error, in all versions of C).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I stand corrected, thanks. I do believe that precise terms are to be used in engineering to convey the right meaning; fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. For curiosity's sake (only), you could write `add(x, y) { return x + y; }` as the function definition, and both the types of the parameters and the return type would be defaulted to `int`.  C89 allowed this — it was necessary to accommodate the existing C code base. C99 technically made the 'implicit int' obsolete, so the code would have to be `int add(x, y) int x, y; { return x, y; }` — but that's not the recommended style (`int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }` is clean in C99 or C11). I learned C a year or so before the book came out — and got it shortly after. It was invaluable.